# Can't Sign up/Sign in to Power BI Community

Tags: powerbi

Since Power BI changed their policy about allowing signing up to Power BI Community with organizationnal email only, I can't register nor login. It redirects me to oauth, then to the community page and i'm using my work email. My work emails works fine with azure portal or power bi service.

Can't file a support ticket either since it's only available to Power BI Pro users.

Comment: You should contact an administrator from your organization regarding this issue.

Comment: FYI, while this is a valid question, it's considered off-topic for stackoverflow since it's not within the scope of programming.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov regarding what parameters?

Comment: @AlexisOlson okay, it's regarding a configuration issue in the organization then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved this by asking the admin to reset my account password.